# Creating a landing page with fullscreen video, music on loop in background, and picture in the center

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to create a website that consists only of a full screen video, with a picture overlay in the center, and music in the background. I have been able to do this successfully, but when viewing on mobile, it goes to trash.

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#video_overlays {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<audio autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
  <source src="h.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="h.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video loop autoplay muted poster="3.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="video_overlays">
    <img src="2.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

For any website to look and function correctly on mobile you need to ensure you implement responsive design into your CSS. This isnt the best site but please see some information here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp  This will provide you with everything you will need to display the video and image correctly on mobile.